# JQuery and Dynamic Table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build somewhat of a shopping cart with jquery and I am having a heck of a time figuring out how to go about making it all work.

I have a place for someone to buy ad spaces on my website. There will be a table with 5 columns(zip code column(input), service column(select box), ad size(select box), ad price(input readonly), and options column for adding or removing rows. I had everything working correctly until I wanted to add an option for large or small ads and charge a different price according to the ad size.

```
        <table style='width: 100%;' id='adsTable'>
            <tr class='addedRow'>
                <td>Zip</td>
                <td>Service</td>
                <td>Ad Size</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>Options</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='text' maxlength='5' class='zip' /></td>
                <td>
                    <select name='serviceType' class='serviceType rounded'>
                        <option value="">Choose One...</option>
                        <option>Plumbing</option>
                        <option>Roofing</option>
                        <option>HVAC</option>
                        <option>Appliance Repair</option>
                        <option>Flooring</option>
                        <option>Electrical</option>
                        <option>Doors/Windows</option>
                        <option>Siding</option>
                        <option>Other</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name='' class='ad_size'>
                        <option value='4.99' class='ad_lg'>Large</option>
                        <option value='1.99' class='ad_sm'>Small</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-usd"></i></span>
                        <input class='addPrice' value='4.99' type='text' readonly='readonly' />
                    </div>
                </td>
                    <td class='options'>

                    </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

I stripped my jquery out and started over a few times to try and figure it all out but keep getting stuck on how to add all the inputs up after the selection of an ad size. Heres the jquery I ended with before I came here

```
    //Varible that stores the extra table row
    var $adTableRow = "<tr class='addedRow'><td><input type='text' maxlength='5' /></td><td><select name='serviceType' id='serviceType' class='rounded'><option value=''>Choose One...</option><option>Plumbing</option>    <option>Drain Cleaning</option><option>Roofing</option><option>HVAC</option><option>Appliance Repair</option><option>Flooring</option>  <option>Electrical</option><option>Doors/Windows</option><option>Siding</option><option>Other</option></select></td><td><select name='' class='ad_size'><option value='4.99' class='ad_lg'>Large</option><option value='1.99' class='ad_sm'>Small</option></select></td><td><div class='input-prepend'><span class='add-on'><i class='icon-usd'></i></span><input class='addPrice' value='4.99' type='text' readonly='readonly' /></div></td><td class='options'><i class='icon-remove removeAd' title='Remove This Ad'></i></td></tr>";

    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('#addTotalBox').val("4.99");
        //Assign the right price amount according to users selection
        $(".ad_size").on('change', function() {
            //Grab the value of the select box and store it in a variable
            var ad_cost = $(this).val();
            //Insert the value into the pricing box             
            $(this).parent().next().children().find('.addPrice').val(ad_cost);
            //Set the total box to the right price according to ad size
            $('input').each(function(index,data) {
                var value = $(this).val();
            });
        });

        $('.addRow').on('click', function() {
            $("#adsTable").append($adTableRow);
            firstRow = false;


            //var addedAdPrice = $(this).parent().prev().children().find('.addPrice').val();

        });
                });
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: What's the problem?  Seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/QwnuR/1/ The price is updated when they change "ad size."

Comment: I add functionality for you to add new rows which will also be updated when you change the "ad size" http://jsfiddle.net/QwnuR/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments above, you need to put your logic into a function, and then re-initialize that function whenever you add a new row.

```
function reInit(){
    $(".ad_size").on('change', function() {
        console.log('test');
        //Grab the value of the select box and store it in a variable
        var ad_cost = $(this).val();
        //Insert the value into the pricing box             
        $(this).parent().next().children().find('.addPrice').val(ad_cost);
        //Set the total box to the right price according to ad size
        $('input').each(function(index,data) {
            var value = $(this).val();
        });
    });
}
```

Then, call it:

```
$('.addRow').on('click', function() {
    $("#adsTable").append($adTableRow);
    firstRow = false;

    reInit();
    //var addedAdPrice = $(this).parent().prev().children().find('.addPrice').val();

});
```

Here's the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QwnuR/2/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I sometimes get overwhelemed by all the moving parts to something like this and don't think about grouping it all into a function. I forgot to add the part where it sums the pricing column and adds it to a readonly input. How would I go about looping through all those inputs to come up with a total of all the ads?

Comment: @AirBiscuit See this code and mark answer :) http://jsfiddle.net/QwnuR/3/ I created a "calculate" method which runs whenever they add a new row or change the size.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I figured it out and came back here to let you know but you already posted an update. :) Jquery is fun but when there are issues it can be frustrating.

Comment: I use a lot of console.log() whenever I run into any issues.

Comment: I seen that, thanks for leaving those comments in there. I usually use alert but console.log is not an annoyance like alert. I am still learning the best way for debugging everything so every piece of info helps.